# How can I deploy Ruby On Rails Application in Apache in LAMP on ubuntu without installing Ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, apache, lamp

Please provide me the guidance for deploying the ruby on rails application in apache in lamp without installing Ruby or rails?

Comment: So you want to deploy an application built using ROR without having Any of the depenedencies installed. Do you want to install them at deploy time or are you expecting that that it is somehow possible to run a ruby application without a ruby interpertor?

Comment: Whoever answers that please include his beef stroganoff recipe that doesn't use beef

Answer (score 1):

You need it. Install ruby with all dependencies and install Phusion Passanger. The way I read your question was like this, lets go ride the bicycle with no wheels, let me check my email with no browser - it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

you may use Phusion Passenger with Apache for deploying the ruby on rails application.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Ubuntu, all the dependencies are just an apt-get line of code away, so it is well worth install it someway